# How to create a javascript object like Date()?

Tags: javascript, date

I wonder how is it possible to create an object for example MyObject() which it can act like javascript Date object when we `+(new MyObject())` like:

```
var a = new Date();
alert(+a);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object needs to have a `valueOf` method like so:

```
var f=new function(){
    this.valueOf=function(){
        return 5;
    }
};
alert(+f); // Displays 5
```

If you don't want to define the method on the object but on its `prototype` as the comments suggested, use the following:

```
function MyObject(value){
    this.value = value;
}
MyObject.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return this.value
}

var o = new MyObject(17);
alert(+o); // Displays 17
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but you could have used an object literal. Or, to stick to the original question, create a constructor and define `valueOf` on the `prototype`. +1 otherwise.

Comment: @Ionuț G. Stan: You could use any construct that results in an object with a defined `valueOf` method. Actually, my example uses a constructor (without a name) to create a `valueOf` method per object. You could have created the method within the `prototype` to share it across instances but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and use a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, which changes the `this` property. After defining the function using `function(){}`, add methods to it using `prototype`.

Normally, an instance of a function created using the `new` keyword will return an Object, which reprsents the `this` inside the defined function. When you define a `toString` method, the function will show a custom string when called from within a string context (default `[object Object]`.

Example:

```
function MyClass(value){
     this.value = value
     this.init_var = 1;
}
MyClass.prototype.getInitVar = function(){
    return this.init_var;
}
MyClass.prototype.setInitVar = function(arg_var){
    this.init_var = arg_var;
}
MyClass.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "This class has the following property: " + this.init_var;
}

var class_instance = new MyClass();
class_instance.setInitVar(3.1415);
alert(class_instance)
```

Comment: This is interesting but i wanted integer represent of my object to be something i want. as @Augustus answered, i needed `valueOf()`

Comment: `toString` is called when `valueOf` doesn't exist. Augustus's solution isn't portable, as it does not make use of prototypes.

Comment: Really? i use `this.prototype.valueOf()` its working now, but i will look for any portability issues and will note here if there is any.

Comment: @Rob W: I think it was important to have an object returning a number (see the plus within the alert in the question). You need `valueOf` for this purpose. Regarding portability it should not matter if you define the method on an object directly or on its prototype. I would be interested to learn which portability issues can arise because I can't think of any.

Comment: @AugustusKling You're defining the methods of the class from within the function, which you immediately initialise. It's not possible to create a new instance of the class. There's neither a way to extend the prototype of the class, because it has already been initialised at definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with all of your points but wouldn't call it portability issues. My first example just creates an object (a single object from an constructor function that can only be called once, thus only creates a single object). I added another example that extends the `prototype` to show this approach, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

```
var MyObject = Date;
var b= new MyObject();
alert(+b) //It will display the current date in milliseconds;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think the OP wants to the create his own object, which is converted to some numerical value. He does not want it to *be* `Date`.